# Problema com DRY

Tags: php, dry

O problema: comparar duas arrays e dar um ponto sempre que um número de uma array for maior que a outra.
Ex)

A = [1, 2, 2]

B = [2, 1, 1]

resultado = [2, 1]

A resposta que eu encontrei:

```
function a($a, $b){

    $a1 = 0;
    $b1 = 0;

    if ($a[0] > $b[0]) {
        $a1++;
    }
    if ($a[1] > $b[1]) {
        $a1++;
    }
    if ($a[2] > $b[2]) {
        $a1++;
    }

    if ($a[0] < $b[0]) {
        $b1++;
    }
    if ($a[1] < $b[1]) {
        $b1++;
    }
    if ($a[2] < $b[2]) {
        $b1++;
    }

return [$a1, $b1];

}

$a = [5,6,7];
$b = [3,6,10];


var_dump(a($a, $b));
```

Mas sinto que há muita repetição desnecessária nesse código. Alguma dica de aprimoramento?

Comment: A dica é usar um laço mesmo, que para o caso o `for` será o mais apropriado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O que está fazendo é percorrer os dois *arrays* ao mesmo tempo, é exatamente o caso de uso do `for`. Usando ele não só estaria repetindo menos mas também estaria deixando genérico para qualquer tamanho que os *arrays* possuam, desde que sejam do mesmo tamanho (não fiz validação disto). A única desvantagem é que é ligeiramente mais lento, mas é irrisório e em PHP faz zero sentido se preocupar com isso (em outras linguagens quase sempre também é neste caso).

```
function a($a, $b) {
    $a1 = 0;
    $b1 = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        if ($a[$i] > $b[$i]) $a1++;
        if ($a[$i] < $b[$i]) $b1++;
    }
    return [$a1, $b1];
}
$a = [5, 6, 7];
$b = [3, 6, 10];
var_dump(a($a, $b));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yFzPES). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LoopComparingphp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/LoopComparing.php).

Você não está violando o DRY, está repetindo código, são coisas distintas. Eu explico isso em [O DRY é para evitar redundâncias, certo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Uma preocupação mais básica que o DRY é dar nomes significativos para as variáveis e e funções.

Comment: @gmsantos sim, eu comecei interpretando como uma coisa e depois vi que ele queria outra coisa, aí esqueci de mudar isso.

Answer (score 3):

tentei  uma abordagem diferente mas acho que cheguei ao mesmo resultado do colega:

```
  $a1 = 0;
  $b1 = 0;


$a = [5,6,7];
$b = [3,6,10];

    $c = count($a);
    for($i = 0; $i < $c;$i++){

        if($a[$i] > $b[$i]){
            $a1++;
        }
        if($a[$i] < $b[$i]){
            $b1++;
        }
    }

echo "a1: " . $a1;
echo "<br>b1: " . $b1;
```

Comment: Eu tive alguns avisos de offset indefinido com esse código, mas ele funcionou mesmo assim. Legal essa forma de deixar a array abstrata. Eu tive uma ideia parecida, mas eu não estava sabendo como expressar ela no código. Obrigado.

Comment: desculpa mas eu havia errado no "for", o correto é assim: for($i = 0; $i < $c;$i++)  pois o array começa apartir da posição 0 e estava $i <= a $c . ou seja após comparar os itens 0, 1 e 2 ele procurava o 3 que não existe. Já corrigi lá.